# How do I point the fortify scan to the previous scan audited fpr through the command line so that it takes the audit and reflects in the new scan

Tags: merge, fortify

In every fortify scan we get a new fpr. How can I point the scan command to the previous Audited  file, so that there is no new fpr created , just a fpr with new issues and previous audit is created. I know the merging technique after the new fpr is created. But is there a way to point the scan to the previous audited fpr so that the scan result fpr has all audit even before merging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the scan command, the `-f <file>`, have that point to the old FPR file that has audits and it will merge the results in automatically.

Comment: That command carries out both scan and merge? Is it possible to carry that out through jenkins command? If Yes, Please show how. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Should i make that pointed to the audited fpr in the batch file? Can you please let me know how i can point it

Comment: That could work, it depends on how your are using Jenkins.  How ever you call the `-scan` command of `sourceanalyzer`, if the `-f <file>` is the audited file then it will do the merge.